# properly accessing images within a <ul>

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have:

```
<div id="thumbImages">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="thumbimages/test1.jpg" alt="thumb1" width="125" height="100" /></li>
            <li><img src="thumbimages/test2.jpg" alt="thumb2" width="125" height="100" /></li>
            <li><img src="thumbimages/test3.jpg" alt="thumb3" width="125" height="100" /></li>
            <li><img src="thumbimages/test4.jpg" alt="thumb4" width="125" height="100" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

in my HTML

and I am attempting to add button like functionality to the thumbnails with this javascript

```
var isMousedOver = [
false,
false,
false,
false
];

function init()
{
   DoStuffWithThumbs();
}

this.onload = init();

function DoStuffWithThumbs()
{
   var thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbImages");
   var itemsUL = thumbs.getElementsByTagName("ul");
   var itemsLI = itemsUL.item(0).getElementsByTagName("li");
   for (var i = 0; i < itemsLI.length; ++i)
   { 
      var curThumb = itemsLI[i];
      curThumb.onclick = DoStuff(i);
      curThumb.onmouseover = MouseOver(i);
      curThumb.onmouseout = MouseOut(i);
   }
}

function MouseOver(val)
{
   isMousedOver[val] = true;
}

function MouseOut(val)
{
   isMousedOver[val] = false;
}

function DoStuff(val)
{
   if(isMousedOver[val] == true)
   {
       //stuff is done here ( I know the stuff in question is working)
   }
}
```

However currently I am getting no visible response from this at all on the page when I have separately tested the result itself ( simply flipping an image and changing some text on the page based on another array). Which leads me to believe I am accessing the elements incorrectly. I am new to using Javascript alongside html so forgive me if I have made some grave error. Am I accessing my elements properly? or is this entirely the wrong way to go about accessing them/using onmouseover/onmouseout?

Comment: You are doing some javascript gymnastics which could be better performed by established libraries. I suggest checking out [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to lessen what you have to write from scratch.

Comment: @VKen: Basic DOM selection and event handling is gymnastics? jQuery isn't the solution to every JS problem.

Comment: @user1689607 I agree with you that jQuery isn't the solution to every JS problem. I have a preference for subjectively cleaner looking javascript. The selection of images in the question could have been as simple as `$('#thumbImages img').click(DoStuff)`. I'm not trying to be offensive here, but to suggest a tool which greatly helped my work in web development. It's a pain to deal with cross-browser problems, and libraries such as this handles that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking functions instead of assigning them as handlers. So you need to fix that first. To fix it according to your current approach, each function you invoke would need to *return* a function that references the current `i` value.

But instead of tracking the mouseover state in an Array, it would be simpler to track it on the DOM element itself by adding a property.

```
function DoStuffWithThumbs() {
   var thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbImages"),
       itemsUL = thumbs.getElementsByTagName("ul"),
       itemsLI = itemsUL.item(0).getElementsByTagName("li");

   for (var i = 0; i < itemsLI.length; ++i) { 
      itemsLI[i].onclick = DoStuff;
      itemsLI[i].onmouseover = MouseOver;
      itemsLI[i].onmouseout = MouseOut;
   }
}

function MouseOver(val) {
   this._over = true;
}

function MouseOut(val) {
   this._over = false;
}

function DoStuff(val) {
   if(this._over === true) {
       // do your stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this ended up being exactly what I needed to know as I had apparently been in the wrong mindset as to what everything was actually doing, I come from a C background so the way this code is working is very strange to me, but this did show me what I needed to know. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1730247: You're welcome. FYI, functions are objects that can be passed like any other data. So what happened was that each element received references to the 3 function objects, which will be invoked as events occur. The `this` value inside the handler is a reference to the element, which can be very handy.